# RSpec: stub method call for external object inside method

Tags: rspec, mocking, stub

I'm attempting to stub the behavior of a method within a method:

```
class A
  def method_one(an_argument)
  begin
    external_obj = ExternalThing.new
    result = external_obj.ext_method(an_argument)
  rescue Exception => e
    logger.info(e.message)
  end
  end
end
```

Spec:

```
it "should raise an Exception when passed a bad argument" do
  a = A.new
  external_mock = mock('external_obj')
  external_mock.stub(:ext_method).and_raise(Exception)
  expect { a.method_one("bad") }.to raise_exception
end
```

However, an Exception never gets raised.

I've also tried:

```
it "should raise an Exception when passed a bad argument" do
  a = A.new
  a.stub(:ext_method).and_raise(Exception)
  expect { a.method_one("bad") }.to raise_exception
end
```

and that doesn't work either. How can one properly stub the external method to force an Exception in this case?

Thanks in advance for any ideas!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to stub the class method `new` of `ExternalThing` and make it return the mock:

```
it "should raise an Exception when passed a bad argument" do
  a = A.new
  external_obj = mock('external_obj')
  ExternalThing.stub(:new) { external_obj }
  external_obj.should_receive(:ext_method).and_raise(Exception)
  expect { a.method_one("bad") }.to raise_exception
end
```

Note that this solution is deprecated in rspec 3. For solution not deprecated in rspec 3 see [rspec 3 - stub a class method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25066699/rspec-3-stub-a-class-method).

Comment: Beautiful. @shioyama - that was exactly what was missing. I'd been pounding my head on that one for too long! Thank you, thank you, thank you!