# rspec 3 - stub a class method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, rspec3

I am upgrading from rspec 2.99 to rspec 3.0.3 and have converted instance methods to use `allow_any_instance_of`, but haven't figured out how to stub a class method. I have code like this:

```
module MyMod
  class Utils
    def self.find_x(myarg)
      # Stuff
    end
  end
end
```

and my rspec 2 test does this:

```
MyMod::Utils.stub(:find_x).and_return({something: 'testing'})
```

What is the Rspec 3 way of doing this?

Answer (score 205, accepted):

You should do

```
allow(MyMod::Utils).to receive(:find_x).and_return({something: 'testing'})
```

Check out the doco [*Method  stubs*](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-mocks#method-stubs).

Comment: I'm trying to implement this but when I write that mock and then write `expect(Class.foo).to eq(bar)` I get a "wrong number of arguments error" because the `foo` method normally wants 2 arguments....but I just want it to return what I put in the stub

Comment: FWIW, this form would crash my ruby interpreter.  However, and_return is not strictly needed and can be left off.  (My ruby interpreter also doesn't crash.)

Comment: @sixty4bit Is there a reason you can't call it with arguments?

Comment: @sixty4bit
`expect(Class.foo).to receive(bar).with(arg1, arg2).and_return({..object})`