# How to stub class variable in method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

Need help ;) Here is example of the code:

```
def some_method
  @some_variable = "some logic for a few strings and operations"
end
```

I want to stub this method like a

```
controller.stub(:some_method).and_return( ??? )
```

But @some_variable should be defined also, how I can do that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [rspec 3 - stub a class method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25066699/rspec-3-stub-a-class-method)

Comment: I suspect you mean instance variable, not class variable?

Answer (score 6):

You can stub it like

```
allow(controller).to receive(:some_method) { your_return_value }
```

Just using the new syntax for stubbing above.

For your instance variable, you can do

```
controller.instance_variable_set(:@some_variable, value)
```